# Function parameter returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here. When trying to log the value of artistBox in the hideProductCard function, it's returning 'undefined'. However, when logging the value of artistBox in the addArtistSelection function it returns with the correct value. Why is this happening? Both functions, as seen in the 'if/else if conditionals' are taking the same parameter and it is being passed along to both functions, but only one is working.

```js
// Adding Artist Selection
let artistCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.artist-filter-input');
let artistProductCards = document.querySelectorAll('.store-card');

artistCheckBoxes.forEach((artistBox) => {
    artistBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (artistBox.checked === true) {
            addArtistSelection(artistBox);
            hideProductCard(artistBox);
        } else if (artistBox.checked === false) {
            document.getElementById(`${artistBox.value}-selection`).remove();
        }
    });
});

let addArtistSelection = (artistBox) => {
    let artistSelectionContainer = document.querySelector('.artist-selection-container');
    let artistSelection = document.createElement('p');
    artistSelection.classList = 'filter-selection artist-selection';
    artistSelection.id = `${artistBox.value}-selection`;
    artistSelection.innerHTML = `
                    ${artistBox.value}
                `;
    artistSelectionContainer.appendChild(artistSelection);
};

let hideProductCard = (artistBox) => {
    artistProductCards.forEach((productCard) => {
        console.log(productCard.querySelector('.card-title').innerText);
        console.log(artistBox.value);
    });
};
```

Comment: Suggestion: Put a debug breakpoint inside your `addArtistSelection` function, step through line by line, and watch the value of `artistBox`. Maybe your DOM manipulations (`.innerHtml = ...` are clobbering the `artistBox` element?

Comment: @Martin_W Thanks for the reply. Just went through addArtistSelection function line by line using the debugger and the value stayed correct. I also logged artistBox.value at the end of the function and it spit out the correct value. No idea what's going on here.

Comment: Hmmm... keep using the debugger. What is the value of `artistBox` *between* `addArtistSelection(artistBox)` and `hideProductCard(artistBox)`. And what happens to it within `hideProductCard(artistBox)`?

Comment: @Martin_W I got it to work. I'm still pretty new to coding so I'm not sure what the reason for this is, but rather than having the two functions (addArtistSelection & hideProductCard) in the if statement, I moved the hideProductCard to the end of the addArtistSelection function. Hopefully that's okay to do. Still curious why it wasn't originally working though.

Comment: And maybe someone else on SO will spot something in the code we missed... But sometimes it's a matter of "it's working now... move on!"